# Cypher query using foreach

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to make relationships between users with same pincode. My data looks like below:

```
User Pincodes
A [111,222]
B [111,333]
C [333,444]
D [111,222]
```

So, I want to create relationships between A and B as they have same pincode and another relationship between B an C. I wrote something like below, that is absolutely not what I want.

```
MATCH (a:User),(b:User)
WHERE a.pincode=b.pincode
WITH COLLECT([a,b]) AS its
FOREACH (pincode IN its |
    CREATE (a)-[r:LIVESINSAMEAREAAS]->(b)
);
```

Comment: Witch type of data pincode is? An list of integers?

Comment: That is: have you nodes like `(:User {pincode : [111,222]})`?

Comment: Have you considered modeling this differently? Using unique :Pincode nodes for pincodes, and relationships to users who have them? That makes finding users with a pincode in common trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

From the comments:

> I have added one new record in my question(please see above). Now if I
>   use your query, it will create a relationship between A, B and D.
>   There is another common pincode between A and D and this is getting
>   included in the previous relationship itself. Can we update your query
>   such that the two different realationships are included?

This query using [filter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-filter) and [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/foreach/) should work:

```
MATCH (a:User),(b:User)
WHERE id(a) > id(b)
WITH a, b, filter(ap in a.pincodes where ap in b.pincodes) as pincodes
FOREACH (pc in pincodes | CREATE (a)-[:LIVESINSAMEAREAAS]->(b))
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I'm assuming that `pincode` is a list of integers. So I created this sample data based on your question:

```
create (:User {pincodes : [111,222]}) 
create (:User {pincodes : [111,333]}) 
create (:User {pincodes : [333,444]})
```

I wrote a query to get all nodes that have at least one in common `pincode`. Then a relationship `:LIVESINSAMEAREAAS` is created between these nodes.

```
MATCH (a:User),(b:User)
WHERE id(a) > id(b) AND ANY (ap in a.pincodes WHERE ap IN b.pincodes)
CREATE (a)-[r:LIVESINSAMEAREAAS]->(b)
```

The first condition in the WHERE (`id(a) > id(b)`) is used to avoid a cartesian product and the creation of the relationship in both directions. That is: (a)-->(b) and (b)-->(a).

In the second condition I'm filtering pair of nodes that at least one pincode of `a` is contained in the list of pincodes of `b`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is working absolutely correct. But I just thought of one use-case. I have added one new record in my question(please see above). Now if I use your query, it will create a relationship between A, B and D. There is another common pincode between A and D and this is getting included in the previous relationship itself. Can we update your query such that the two different realationships are included?

Comment: Hello @user2720919, you are welcome. I have updated my answer. Take a look! Thanks!

Comment: Neo4j 'filter' function is no longer supported

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution from [@Bruno Peres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504678/4989460) works, it will be reasonable to follow the spirit of the graphs, and make the area a separate node. For example:

```
MATCH (U:User) UNWIND U.pincodes as pincode
MERGE (A:Area {pincode: pincode})
MERGE (U)-[:liveInTheArea]->(A)
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thank you. Both solution works. However, I would like to comment on your solution with respect to my scope. I want to figure out most important users using betweenness centrality. The algorithm is provided by Neo4j. The query would look like: CALL algo.betweenness.stream('User','liveInTheArea', {direction:'', write:true, writeProperty:'centrality'}) yield nodeId,centrality RETURN nodeId, centrality.

Comment: As based on your solution, we have created two different labels and I don't think the algorithm provides a way to give two different labels, can you think of a way to solve this issue and get the most important users?